# Select from two tables and update the correct table?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have the following to search and select from 2 tables

```
SELECT table_a.*, table_b.* 
FROM table_a 
LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.visitorBarcode = table_b.business_barcode 
WHERE table_a.visitorBarcode LIKE '00996689' OR table_b.business_barcode LIKE '00996689'
```

Now the barcode value (i.e. 00996689 ) is found in either table_a or table_b and i like to update a particular column in the specific table. These are the queries i use for individual updates

```
UPDATE table_a SET entered = '1' WHERE visitorBarcode = '00996689';

UPDATE table_b SET entered = '1' WHERE business_barcode = '00996689';
```

But how can i switch between these two queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I see no need to combine those queries, but you can do it like this:</s>

```
UPDATE table_a a JOIN table_b b ON a.visitorBarcode = b.business_barcode
SET a.entered = '1',
b.entered = '1'
WHERE a.visitorBarcode = '00996689';
```

Well, why worry? If the record is not found, then the update statement doesn't do any harm. Just execute both queries and that's it. Otherwise you'd have to write a procedure or something to first look for the record and so on. In my opinion it's not worth the trouble. Performancewise you won't gain anything.

Comment: sorry i didn't mean combine but more one or the other query to use